# Illegal Start of Expression

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Компилятор ругается, выдает illegal start of expression. Погуглил, но решение так и не нашел, а если и нашел, то видимо не понял :(

Помогите, пожалуйста :)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public int rollDice() {

            double randomNumber = Math.random();

            randomNumber = randomNumber * 6;

            randomNumber = randomNumber + 1;

            int randomInt = (int) randomNumber;

            return randomInt;
        }
        int rollOne = rollDice();
        int rollTwo = rollDice();
        System.out.println("Roll 1: " + rollOne);
        System.out.println("Roll 2: " + rollTwo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынесите `public int rollDice() { ... }` из `main` в тело класса.

После этого у Вас будет ошибка про использование метода экземпляра внутри статического, которая чинится изменением декларации на `private static int rollDice() { ... }`.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Я просто только учу Java, поэтому задаю такие глупые вопросы :,)